# Good book on Lebesgue Theory

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, lebesgue-measure, book-recommendation, big-list

I am a graduate student and I need a suggestion for a good book in Lebesgue Measure Theory with good exercises and if its possibly with hints or solutions.
Thank you.

Comment: Intro to measure theory by james yeah.

Answer (score 2):

The standard options for graduate students these days are:

- Rudin, Real & Complex Analysis 3e
- Folland, Real Analysis and its Applications 2e
- Royden & Fitzpatrick, Real Analysis 4e

I'm partial to the second one myself.

Answer (score 2):

A great one is [Real Analysis For Graduate Students](http://homepages.uconn.edu/~rib02005/real.html) by Richard F. Bass.  The chapters are quite concise, but his writing is very clear and there are lots of exercises.  The book focuses on measure theory and Lebesgue integration, and later chapters deal with formalizing probability, Sobolev spaces, and distributions.  The best part is that author has it on his website for free distribution.  The paperback is pretty cheap too.

Comment: However, as the author mentions in the preface: "I cannot, however, provide hints or solutions to the exercises." So this may not be the best suggestion given the OP's request.

Comment: Sorry, just noticed that this is an old question/answer. Someone edited the question, which necro'd the thread.